# Can we please add a Line Counter to the Edit Window?

Tags: feature-request, editor

After reading yet another case of "I'll post all my code so they don't tell me I left something out" ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30153103/asp-net-using-vb-net-button-event-handler-not-fired-and-the-text-box-value-not)). It struck me:

Maybe if we showed the user a line counter, maybe with a statistic like "Your post is longer than 90% of the posts on this site", then the user might stop to think before posting their *entire program*.

Comment: "then a user might stop to think" lets keep that hope

Comment: Link to MCVE thing too.

Comment: Conversely maybe "your question is shorter than 90% of all non-closed questions -- have you included enough information to get an answer?" will help (also MCVE, this time about the C)... but users never read.

Comment: At least he's respectful in the comments. There's so many instance of that where people are just like "Give me the code!" or "Please bro, I'm desperate!" So many times has that happened... To the person who conversed with him, you are now a sir!

Comment: At what point will the site just have an AI personality that checks the content and quality of questions itself?

Comment: @TylerH: I didn't ask for any intelligence. I asked to show the editor information he might use to decide to post less code.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - you should just hack it down to only what is relevant for them

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: but that would require intelligence on _my_ part.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - more important that is time for me ... ;-)

Comment: The first comment on the linked question is "Can you post your markup?"

Comment: Not a bad thing because it is more just a warning/info and does not from stop posting. Users who care would think twice and those who don't...well, they would continue doing whatever they do today. So there is atleast some chance for improvement.

Comment: The problem with computed metrics is that they need to target a vast majority if we are going to apply validation/warnings to them. I don't think you can do that with this metric.

Comment: Also, think about all the posts about it on meta.. "I was asked to include my code, then this warning popped up telling me my post is too long!!111"

Comment: @CarrieKendall: that just means we need to do something intelligent like say, "When we asked you to include code, we didn't mean for you to include your entire _project_!"

Comment: I understand your frustration but this feature-request would add more problems than it would solve.

Comment: I'd like to have line numbers just to make the referencing various lines of code easier.  I would upvote just that part, but have no desire to include a message beyond that.

Comment: I would actually prefer line numbers in code snippets:) or at least the option to enable them

Answer (score 18):

Having too much code can be problematic, but only if it represents a failure to make a minimum, compilable, verifiable example.

Personally, it's far more common for questions to contain too little, and there are a lot of cases where larger quantities of code have been helpful in making a good answer. For example, [Why is PySide's exception handling extending this object's lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086365/why-is-pysides-exception-handling-extending-this-objects-lifetime/26087780) was a breeze to debug due to the complete example and thorough explanation, despite being larger than average.

I think having such a system risks discouraging good questions like the above, and bad long question dumps won't be made better by being haplessly shortened - if anything they'll become *even more* cryptic.

I may be biased; I have [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040198/cpython-string-addition-optimisation-failure-case) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078734/recursive-lambda-callbacks-without-y-combinator) [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26943481/catch-errors-during-object-construction-from-try-with-resources-separately-from) [long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477791/assignment-within-raii-scope) questions - and some *are* probably too long - but this seems like a warning too many.

Comment: That's true, but a warning is different than an error.  If you're stopping to think about the message and it if applies to you, then it has already succeeded.  Unlike some other automated post quality control messages, this needn't be enforced before submitting a question.